# Como eu recupero a informação de uma janela Java em uma ComboBox de outra janela?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Eu tenho um cadastro de fornecedores e um de produtos, e gostaria de recuperar na janela de cadastro de produtos a informação de quais fornecedores já estão cadastrados para poder salvar no produto, mas não entendo como realizar isso.
Por enquanto ainda não usamos BD, então as informações estão guardadas apenas na memória
Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
public class CadastroProduto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private LinkedList<Produto> listaProdutos;
private LinkedList<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores;
private Produto produto;
private Fornecedor fornecedor;
private boolean novo = false;



/**
 * Creates new form Produto
 */
public CadastroProduto(LinkedList listaProdutos, Produto produto) {
    initComponents();
    this.listaProdutos = listaProdutos;
    this.listaFornecedores = listaFornecedores;
    this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    this.produto = produto;


    comboProduto.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaProdutos.toArray()));
    comboFornecedor.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaFornecedores.toArray()));
    btNovo.setEnabled(true);

}
```

Também tentei passar listaFornecedores e fornecedor como parâmetros de CadastroProduto, mas também deu erro

O meu

```
 comboFornecedor.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaFornecedores.toArray()));
```

Foi só uma das tentativas, não sei nem se eu preciso usar o this.listaFornecedores e o this.fornecedor nesse caso dentro de CadastroProduto...

Answer (score 0):

Você ja tentou algo do tipo, colocar um setListaFornecedores em Produtos?

```
public class CadastroProduto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private LinkedList<Produto> listaProdutos;
private LinkedList<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores;
private Produto produto;
private Fornecedor fornecedor;
private boolean novo = false;



/**
 * Creates new form Produto
 */
public CadastroProduto(LinkedList listaProdutos, Produto produto) {
    initComponents();
    this.listaProdutos = listaProdutos;
    this.listaFornecedores = listaFornecedores;
    this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    this.produto = produto;


    comboProduto.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaProdutos.toArray()));
    comboFornecedor.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaFornecedores.toArray()));
    btNovo.setEnabled(true);


    setListaFornecedores(LinkedList<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores){
       this.listaFornecedores = listaFornecedores;
    }

}
```

E em fornecedores você setar os fornecedores em produtos ?

```
comboFornecedor.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(listaFornecedores.toArray()));
produtos.setListaFornecedores(listaFornecedores);
```

Tenta algo tipo assim ...
Abraço